# Title next to horizontal navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a simple webpage (following tutorials). I have created a menu bar, title and text content. I want to have the title to the left of the menu bar. So that at the top (working left to right) you have the title then menu.

I've read that you should use `float: left;` to achieve this, but it didn't work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1><font face="Arial" color="black" size="8">Project Name</font></h1>
    <p>This is a simple test Page

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    float: left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50
}

body {
    background-color: #ECECEC
}
```

Currently the title is below the menu but to the left of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/wCV2X/1/

How do I get it so the menu and title are in line?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to write <h1> before the <ul> if you want to work from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:
Then you should have a nice menu with your title or logo on the left.
`Float: left` follows the order of elements, so you should place the title before the menu to let it appear on the left.

```css
p {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height:13px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50
}

body {
    background-color: #ECECEC
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
  
    <ul>
    <p><font face="Arial" color="white" size="4">Project Name</font></p>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="pagecontent">
      <p>This is a simple test Page

    </p>
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1 {
    float: left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50
}

body {
    background-color: #ECECEC
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
 <h1><font face="Arial" color="black" size="8">Project Name</font></h1>
    <ul>
        
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <p>This is a simple test Page

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now Title and menu are inline you can change css according to your needs

Comment: That works sort of how I wanted it. How do I get the title to line up with the centre of the menu?

Comment: @JackU make the H1 font size smaller and Set the `line-height` as high as the height of the menu

Comment: @JackU check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Move your `<h1>` to the beginning of your menu bar and put it inside a `<li>` like this:

```css
h1 {
    float: left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50
}

body {
    background-color: #ECECEC
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li><h1><font face="Arial" color="black" size="8">Project Name</font></h1></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>This is a simple test Page

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```